# Coloring edges of $K_{n,n}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an edge set $T$ of a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ such that $|T|=n+2$ for $n\ge 4$, can we find a proper edge coloring of $K_{n,n}$ (if two edges are incident, then they receive different colors) using $n$ colors such that any color class intersects with $T$ in at most two edges?

Comment: Find two matchings containing exactly two edges from $T$, then show that you can always extract matchings containing exactly one edge from $T$.

Comment: How do we find two perfect matchings that each intersect with $T$ at exactly two edges?

Comment: Try to apply Hall's theorem

Comment: Not that simple I think. In some configurations, for some two non-incident edges of $T$,  all perfect matchings containing them contains another edge of $T$.

Comment: In this situation, you should find by applying Hall's theorem that all the remaining T edges are incident to the same vertex. From this, you should find a pair that works